# Weird cell placement in a tikz matrix

Tags: positioning, tikz-matrix

The code

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes, column sep = {1.5cm,between origins}, row sep = 1cm]
{
&|(1)|1\\
|(nnjtoj)|\neg\neg jo\to jo&&|(nnjtojtojnj)|(\neg\neg jo\to jo)\to j\neg jo\\
&|(jnj)|j\neg jo&&|(nnj)|\neg\neg jo\\
|(nj)|\neg jo&&|(j)|jo\\
&|(o)|o\\
};
\draw (1) -- (nnjtoj) -- (jnj) -- (nj) -- (o) -- (j) -- (nnj) -- (nnjtojtojnj) -- (1);
\draw (j) -- (jnj) -- (nnjtojtojnj);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

results in
[image]

Why is the rightmost cell placed so far? I've been able to correct it by inserting `[-10ex]` at an appropriate place but still wonder -- what might be the reason?

Comment: I see now the answer, in time of  writing of my comment it wasn't here (in my PC, so I will erase comment as surplus ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug, in fact the behavior is (indirectly) documented in the manual:

> *The `between origins` option can only be used for columns mentioned in the first row, that is, you
>   cannot specify this option for columns introduced only in later rows.*

(Section 20.3.2 *Setting and Adjusting Column and Row Spacing*)

In your matrix you only have one column in the first row, so the `between origins` only applies to the first column. The fix is simple though: add empty columns in the first row:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes, column sep = {1.5cm,between origins}, row sep = 1cm]
{
 & |(1)|1 & & \\ % <-- Added two & here
|(nnjtoj)|\neg\neg jo\to jo & & |(nnjtojtojnj)|(\neg\neg jo\to jo)\to j\neg jo\\
 & |(jnj)|j\neg jo & & |(nnj)|\neg\neg jo\\
|(nj)|\neg jo & & |(j)|jo\\
 &|(o)|o\\
};
\draw (1) -- (nnjtoj) -- (jnj) -- (nj) -- (o) -- (j) -- (nnj) -- (nnjtojtojnj) -- (1);
\draw (j) -- (jnj) -- (nnjtojtojnj);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]